# Add comment to SQL table

Tags: migration, yii2

How can I add comment for specific SQL-table in Yii2 migration?

SQL code:

> ALTER TABLE `my_table` COMMENT 'Hello World'

I wand to do in within a migration in ORM way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In yii2 format

- addCommentOnColumn($table, $column, $comment)
- dropCommentFromColumn($table, $column)
- addCommentOnTable($table, $comment)
- dropCommentFromTable($table)

Example: In migration file

```
$this->addCommentOnColumn('user','role_id','Relation table of role');
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no such functionality in Yii 2 migrations.

You have to write it in plain SQL via [execute()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-migration.html#execute%28%29-detail) method:

```
$this->execute("ALTER TABLE my_table COMMENT 'Hello World'");
```